# Disallow changing Work Order status to Complete, if any of the tasks are not complete

Tags: configuration, customization, maximo

I have a work order in Maximo that has tasks.

[image]

I want to configure Maximo so that the work order cannot be changed to complete if any of the tasks are not complete.

Reason: I want to do this to ensure that none of the tasks are accidently missed when the work order is changed to complete.

**How can I do this?**

*My consultant has suggested that this can only be done with Java customization of Maximo. I would like to verify if this is the only option.*

Version: 7.6.1.1

Comment: For what it's worth, I think this (or something close to it) might be possible with Flow Control.

Answer (score 2):

From the screen shot, it looks like you're on Maximo 7.6.1. So, Java is certainly not the only option.

One of the ways to do this without any "coding" (other than a Conditional Expression, which doesn't count) is to put a Conditional Expression on synonyms of Complete in the WOSTATUS Synonym Domain. This solution will prevent synonyms of Complete from showing up in the list of statuses you can choose from unless the condition evaluates to true.

If you want to use Automation Scripts, you could call one from an Object Launch Point or from an Attribute Launch Point and have it throw an error if a situation like the screenshot would result.

Alternatively to the above, you could choose to have Tasks inherit status changes from the parent automatically, in which case the Tasks in your screenshot would have changed to COMP when the WO they are under changed to COMP. You can configure "Inherit status changes" to be true by default and configure whether users can override that default.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/IBM+Maximo+Asset+Management/page/Restricting+closure+of+parent+work+orders

> Restricting closure of parent work orders when child or task work
>   orders are in process You can restrict users from closing a parent
>   work order if any child or task work order is not closed, completed,
>   or canceled. You create a conditional expression and apply it to the
>   WOSTATUS domain closed, canceled, and complete values.

If all tasks must be completed and you don't care about parent/child work orders, then you can use the following condition instead:

`not exists (select 1 from workorder where parent = :wonum
and istask=0 and status not in ('COMP','CLOSE','CAN'))`

Word of warning. Test properly. If you require all tasks be completed, it may affect escalations and technicians may dislike having to check all tasks complete on routine job plans.

Comment: Don't forget to join on siteid, in case the wonum exists in multiple sites. And istask is numeric, so the quotes aren't necessary.

Comment: Fixed numeric single quote.